# Correct approach on throwing raise exception

Tags: python, exception, static-analysis

I have this code smell in my sonarScan which is throwing me
"Add logic to this except clause or eliminate it and rethrow the exception automatically."

for an example , i am trying to raise a fileNotFoundError and code is working perfectly fine in my server . am i doing the right approach on this ?

```
def read_file():
     try:
         with open("/test/test.txt", 'r') as f:
             json_obj = json.load(f)
     except FileNotFoundError as e:
         raise e
```

Comment: If you're re-raising the exact same exception, there's no reason to catch it.  Just let the exception happen.

Comment: You actually made the traceback a little worse because there is this unneeded `raise e` in it.